# Options regarding the properties of Streamreaders and Streamwriters

Tags: vb.net, authentication, streamreader, streamwriter

When using streamreader and streamwriters in code for a login system (where new accounts can be created and existing accounts can be logged into) I have been using:

```
    usernameReader = New StreamReader("J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\Resources\username.txt")
```

The 'New' part of the streamreader is necessary (as the variable cannot equal just the stream), however I was wondering if there were any other options that I could use instead of the 'as new streamreader' to open the stream without erasing the content of the username text file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to avoid writing the word "New" in your code?

Comment: Yeah, I need the username and password text files to keep the data stored in them, but using 'New' in the program as-is clears the two text files of their content.

Comment: The streamreader just reads, it does not perform any writing action (like deleting). With New you create a new instance of the streamreader class, that is, a new place in the memory where the given information will be stored; the contents of the file will not be affected by this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [File.OpenText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you do not need to configure the StreamReader for a more specific scenario. The [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class provides several useful shortcuts for common I/O tasks.

By the way: I don't think that opening a StreamReader erases the file; I'd rather suspect that the code that writes to the files is wrong. It will erase the file if you open the file for writing like this:

```
writer = new StreamWriter("... path ...")
```

Have a look at File.AppendText or something similar.

Comment: When I use the File class, would I replace the declaration statement with: 'Private passwordWriter As File' ? Also, how do I set a file path with regards to the File class?

Comment: You can use the File class without instantiation, e.g. Dim reader = File.OpenText("...path..."). There are lots of overloads for the specific tasks that take the path as a string Parameter.